# Conversion buffer overflow when saving xml file to isolated storage (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to save a xml file to isolated storage for WP7 that i download with a streamreader, but I get a conversion buffer overflow on the save(isostream) statement. I suspect that there is something wrong with my xml file, because if I create a Xdocument manually in C# my saver method works perfect. Anyone that has expereinced something similar? Thanks

code:

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test1.xml", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
                        {
                            xmlDoc.Save(isoStream);
                        }
                    }
```

xml file

```
- <pactrack version="1.0" date="Sat Jan 21 19:22:48 CET 2012" size="276" lang="SE">
  <header /> 
- <body>
  <programevent level="4">måste anges i sökvärdet kolliid: dfs</programevent> 
  </body>
  <footer /> 
  </pactrack>
```

call stack

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Text.Encoder.Convert(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, bool flush, out int charsUsed, out int bytesUsed, out bool completed) + 0x143 bytes    
    System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.FlushEncoder() + 0x31 bytes   
    System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.Flush() + 0xc bytes   
    System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.Close() + 0x4b bytes  
    System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose(bool disposing) + 0x1b bytes    
    System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose() + 0x7 bytes   
    System.Xml.Linq.dll!System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions options) + 0x56 bytes   
    System.Xml.Linq.dll!System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(System.IO.Stream stream) + 0xd bytes 
>   panoramaTest.dll!panoramaTest.MainPage.client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) Line 49 + 0x8 bytes   C#
    System.Net.dll!System.Net.WebClient.OnOpenReadCompleted(System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) + 0x15 bytes   
    System.Net.dll!System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadOperationCompleted(object arg) + 0xc bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, bool isBinderDefault, System.Reflection.Assembly caller, bool verifyAccess, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x168 bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object obj, object[] parameters) + 0xa bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(object[] args) + 0x98 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args) + 0x8 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(object[] args) + 0x2 bytes   
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() + 0xc bytes    
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority) + 0x83 bytes  
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(object context) + 0x8 bytes 
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(object[] args) + 0x19 bytes 
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(object[] args) + 0x2 bytes 
    System.Windows.RuntimeHost.dll!System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(System.IntPtr pHandle, int nParamCount, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam[] pParams, ref System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam pResult) + 0x5e bytes 
    [External Code]
```

Comment: Can you copy the full exception with the callstack?

Comment: Hi, added the full call stack to the inital question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the problem:

```
        var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xml)));

        xmlDoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "iso-8859-1", "yes");

        using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test1.xml", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
            {
                xmlDoc.Save(isoStream);
            }
        }
```

I have yet to understand why, but it seems like it comes from the encoder. Maybe there's some character invalid with the specified encoder?

Anyway, I think you can get around by explicitely switching to unicode:

```
xmlDoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");

using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test1.xml", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
    {
        xmlDoc.Save(isoStream);
    }
}
```

Just make sure that the characters are still good when you read the XML file back from the isolated storage.

Comment: Hi again. I was just writing as i found out the same problem, IsolatedStorageFileStream is not happy with accepting a non utf8 enoding!! I just changed my encoding of the xml header file manually XDocument doc = loadedDataISO;
                    doc.Declaration.Encoding = "UTF-8";
                    XDocument loadedData = doc;             but your solution was more pretty!

Comment: Yes strangly I dont lose the special charaacters after reading them out from the memory, just tried that now. So all works now, but maybe they should add this to the msdn that it does not accept anything else than utf8. Was supprised to not find this problem here already, as this must be encountred pretty often for non english languages users?! Again many thanks for the help!